# CSS line between table-cell divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a basic horizontal timeline, and I can get each element spaced correctly, but I'm stuck drawing lines between them. Here is my html:

```
<ul class="timeline">
    <li><div class="badge"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></li>
    <li><div class="badge"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></li>
    <li><div class="badge"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
.timeline {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.timeline > li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

.timeline > li > .badge {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

This shows three equally spaced circles with a Font Awesome icon in the centre.  Now I want to draw lines between each circle.  I thought that I might need to use `:after` and `:before`, but nothing I've tried has given any result at all.  Here is one attempt:

```
.timeline > li > badge:after {
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the `.timeline > li`:

```
position: relative;
```

And add this new set of rules:

```
.timeline > li:not(:last-child):after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/Lzvxyfv9/

Answer (score 1):

What about this, add `border-right` property to `li`

```
li{ border-right: 1px solid #999999; }
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/tqq13pxz/2)

Answer (score 0):

In css you can do it as:

```
.timeline > li{
    border-right: 1px solid #222222;
}
```

Comment: That draws a line below, not between.  Also, I don't know the width (its responsive) and I want a css solution so that I don't need to go sticking `<hr/>` is everywhere that I use this.

Comment: You need to add <hr> tag wherever you want to display horizantal line.I have updated with css solution too. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `border-right` and it should do it

```
.timeline > li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```