# Add inline horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I have a traffic light like dashboard view which I have to come up with for one of my pages. But I just cannot have the horizontal lines working inspite of multiple tweaks.

What I want: [Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIvbk.png)

Fiddle for what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/gunnersfan/dx19y3f4/

**CSS:**

```
.bubble {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 90%;
}
.red-bg {
  background: red;
}
.green-bg {
  background: green;
}
.blue-bg {
  background: blue;
}

.inline-div {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-family: verdana;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS line between table-cell divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460005/css-line-between-table-cell-divs)

Comment: Just a tip not relating to your question: use `line-height` equal to `height` to make vertically centered your numbers in the circles. In your case so: `line-height: 30px;`

Comment: Thanks @fremail, that was a useful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this for you: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/debute/93ej349p/)

```
.bubbles .line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use HTML Canvas?
but if you really want to use CSS, this is a short way:

```
.shape1 {
  height: 1px;
  width: 104px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid ;
  border-right: 1px solid ;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position:absolute;
}
.shape2 {
  height: 1px;
  width: 104px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid ;
  border-right: 1px solid ;
  margin-left: 214px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position:absolute;
}

<body>
    <div>
        <div class="inline-div">
          Title1
        </div>
        <div class="inline-div">
          Title2
        </div>
        <div class="inline-div">
          Title3
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
  <div class="shape1"></div>
   <div class="shape2"></div>
        <div class="bubble red-bg">
        5
        </div>
        <div class="bubble green-bg">
        66
        </div>

        <div class="bubble blue-bg">
        777
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a bit of `:before` magic.

Add a class to the div that wraps your `bubble` `div`s, say `'outer-bubble'` and add the following CSS:

```
.outer-bubble {
  position: relative;
}

.outer-bubble:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 290px;
  background: black;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx19y3f4/8/)

Comment: This works perfectly for me too, Thanks! Accepted the answer from @debute because it was first.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position: relative` to `.bubble`, you can implement the line in this manner:

```
.bubble:not(:nth-last-of-type(1)):before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 140px;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

So, you're adding `:before` pseudo-element to each `.bubble` but last.

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to add additional markup. And here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0nuq4Ltf/).